# How to make blinking text in python with termcolor?

Tags: python, termcolor

Whenever I try to use termcolor to make blinking text, using the following code:

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint
cprint('\nJames Everleigh', 'red', attrs=['blink'])
```

It prints the text red, but it doesn't blink. Is there some function that I need to use to turn the blinking on/something like that?

I use *replit.com* which is using python 3.8.2. I've also tried Visual Studio but it still doesn't blink.

Comment: Try to use a real terminal. Both replit and VS code do not support all terminal features.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, also, what would be a "real" terminal/what app has one?

Comment: @Mynamejeff The app named Terminal on Linux/MacOS, or PowerShell or cmd.exe on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curses library to do some cool stuff inside a terminal (only for Linux).

Here is the documentation : https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/curses.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try print("\033[5mHello\033[0m\n") (from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269809/blink-codeescape-code-has-been-removed )

It work for me, I'm using terminator. Should work with other terminal emulator too. And according to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal), VScode have an integrated terminal, so you can try with it and tell us how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

The terminal you're using may not support the `blink` attribute. Refer to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) under `Terminal properties` to check if your terminal supports it.